# convert spark dataframe to aws glue dynamic frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I tried converting my spark dataframes to dynamic to output as glueparquet files but I'm getting the error

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fromDF'"

My code uses heavily spark dataframes. Is there a way to convert from spark dataframe to dynamic frame so I can write out as glueparquet?  If so could you please provide an example, and point out what I'm doing wrong below?

code:

```
# importing libraries

import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# updated 11/19/19 for error caused in error logging function

spark = glueContext.spark_session

from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.functions  import date_format
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length, min,when,format_number,dayofmonth,hour,dayofyear,month,year,weekofyear,date_format,unix_timestamp


base_pth='s3://test/'

bckt_pth1=base_pth+'test_write/glueparquet/'


test_df=glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
                 database='test_inventory',
                 table_name='inventory_tz_inventory').toDF()

test_df.fromDF(test_df, glueContext, "test_nest")


glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = test_nest,
                                             connection_type = "s3",
                                             connection_options = {"path": bckt_pth1+'inventory'},
                                             format = "glueparquet")
```

error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fromDF'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1574556353910_0001/container_1574556353910_0001_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1300, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fromDF'
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create dynamic frame from dynamic frame. Can you confirm test_df is a data frame, from the script I see that you are creating it as dynamic frame and not data frame.

Answer (score 35):

`fromDF` is a class function. Here is how you can convert `Dataframe` to `DynamicFrame`

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

DynamicFrame.fromDF(test_df, glueContext, "test_nest")
```

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-fromDF)

Answer (score 13):

Just to consolidate the answers for Scala users too, here's how to transform a Spark Dataframe to a DynamicFrame (the method fromDF doesn't exist in the scala API of the DynamicFrame) :

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame  
val dynamicFrame = DynamicFrame(df, glueContext)
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: probably not the place for this question, but what are the benefit to scala in glue vs pyspark for df transformations and loads?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import Dynamic DataFrame class
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

#Convert from Spark Data Frame to Glue Dynamic Frame
dyfCustomersConvert = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "convert")

#Show converted Glue Dynamic Frame
dyfCustomersConvert.show()
```